# Replace Root with C# driver for .net core AggregateExpressionDefinition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

I'm trying to perform a simple unwind and replace root in .net core 2.2.
I've already tried the query in MongoDB and it works but I'm finding it difficult to translate it 100 % to C# without using magic strings.

This is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6475b20b49a5cec99eb89"),
    "name" : "Route A"
    "isActive" : true,
    "buses" : [ 
        {
            "capacity" : "15",
            "time" : "08:00:00",
            "direction" : "Inbound"
        },
        {
            "capacity" : "15",
            "time" : "08:30:00",
            "direction" : "Inbound"
        },
        {
            "capacity" : "15",
            "time" : "08:00:00",
            "direction" : "Outbound"
        },
        {
            "capacity" : "15",
            "time" : "08:30:00",
            "direction" : "Outbound"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have a class for the root document called Routes and another one for the subdocument called Bus.

The query I'm running in mongo is this one:

```
db.routes.aggregate([
    { $match : { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4e818cb95b3572c8f0f2c") } },
    { $unwind: "$buses" },
    { $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$buses" } }
])
```

The expected result is a simple array of buses, so far I'm getting it with this query in C#

```
_routes.Aggregate()
                .Match(r => r.Id == routeId)
                .Unwind<Route, UnwoundRoute>(r => r.Buses)
                .ReplaceRoot<Bus>("$buses")
                .ToListAsync();
```

I want to know if it's possible to replace the string "$buses" with something that's not hardcoded.

I've tried using the AggregateExpressionDefinition class which is one of the possible parameters that the ReplaceRoot method can receive but I wasn't able to understand it completely.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this here in case someone ends up making the same mistakes I did.

I basically created a new "UnwoundRoute" entity to hold the results of the unwind operation and then used a simple LINQ expression. Thanks to the reddit user u/Nugsly for the suggestion about changing the way I should call unwind.

This works:

```
_routes.Aggregate()
                .Match(r => r.Id == routeId)
                .Unwind<Route, UnwoundRoute>(r => r.Buses)
                .ReplaceRoot(ur => ur.Buses)
                .ToListAsync();
```

You can also filter the result of the replace root afterwards:

```
_routes.Aggregate()
                .Match(r => r.Id == routeId)
                .Unwind<Route, UnwoundRoute>(r => r.Buses)
                .ReplaceRoot(ur => ur.Buses)
                .Match(b => b.Direction == direction)
                .ToListAsync();
```

And it will return an array of documents.

```
{
    "capacity" : "15",
    "time" : "08:00:00",
    "direction" : "Inbound"
},
{
    "capacity" : "15",
    "time" : "08:30:00",
    "direction" : "Inbound"
}
```

Also, if you try to add the result type to replace root VS will throw an error saying that the lambda expression couldn't be converted because it's not a delegate type.

This doesn't (which is what I had in the beggining):

```
_routes.Aggregate()
                .Match(r => r.Id == routeId)
                .Unwind<Route, UnwoundRoute>(r => r.Buses)
                .ReplaceRoot<Bus>(ur => ur.Buses)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

i can offer you a solution that uses MongoDAL, which is just a wrapper around the c# driver which hides most of the complexity of the driver.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDAL;

namespace BusRoutes
{
    class Route : Entity
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public Bus[] buses { get; set; }
    }

    class Bus
    {
        public int capacity { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("busroutes");

            var routeA = new Route
            {
                name = "Route A",
                buses = new Bus[]
                {
                    new Bus { capacity = 15, direction = "Inbound", time = "8:00:00"},
                    new Bus { capacity = 25, direction = "Outbound", time = "9:00:00" },
                    new Bus { capacity = 35, direction = "Inbound", time = "10:00:00" }
                }
            };

            routeA.Save();

            var query = routeA.Collection()
                .Where(r => r.ID == routeA.ID)
                .SelectMany(r => r.buses);

            Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());

            var busesOfRouteA = query.ToArray();

            foreach (var bus in busesOfRouteA)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bus.time.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```