# MongoDB - Use projection to “bind model class” to specific collection node in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, projection

I've the following data structure:

**"settings":**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('636e6724dec4d0de99d1ba25'),
    partnerASettings: {
        user: 'abcA',
        password: 'abcA@123',
        baseUri: 'https://abcA.com/v1/api'
    },
    partnerBSettings: {
        user: 'abcB',
        password: 'abcB@123',
        baseUri: 'https://abcB.com/v1/api'
    }
}
```

And I want to `project` only one of "sub-nodes" in C#, like:

`db.settings.find({},{"partnerBSettings":1})`

Result:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "636e6724dec4d0de99d1ba25"},
    partnerBSettings: {       
       user: 'abcB',
       password: 'abcB@123',
       baseUri: 'https://abcB.com/v1/api'
    }
}
```

**C# Model:**

```
public class Settings
{
    public PartnerASettings PartnerASettings { get; set; }
    public PartnerBSettings PartnerBSettings { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerASettings
{
    public string BaseUri { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerBSettings
{
    public string BaseUri { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I have a generic method to try select only the specific model from node document::

```
TSettings Select<TSettings>()
{
  var projection = Builders<Settings>.Projection.Include(/*???*/);
  
  var settings = _settingsCollection
        .Find(Builders<Settings>.Filter.Empty)
        .Project<TSettings>(projection)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return settings;
}
```

But my doubt is how to `.Project<T>` to my "sub model", like `PartnerBSettings.cs`. What  `Builders<Settings>.Projection` I need? How can I specific it generically?

I wrote a method without "generics" and without specific model at  `.Project` method:

```
PartnerBSettings Select()
{
    var settings = _settingsCollection
        .Find(Builders<Settings>.Filter.Empty)
        .Project(p => p.PartnerBSettings)
        .FirstOrDefault();
        
    return settings;
}
```

And I wrote a method specifying model at `.Project<PartnerBSettings>` method, but it using `BsonDocument` instantiation:

```
PartnerBSettings Select()
{
    var settings = _settings
          .Aggregate()
          .Unwind("partnerBSettings")
          .Find(Builders<Settings>.Filter.Empty)
          .Project<PartnerBSettings>(new BsonDocument()
          {
                { "User", "$partnerBSettings.user" },
                { "Password", "$partnerBSettings.password" },
                { "BaseUri", "$partnerBSettings.baseUri" },
          });
        
    return settings;
}
```

"Generic" version, but still with `new BsonDocument()` and still specify the fields:

```
TSettings Select<TSettings>()
{
    var settings = _settings
          .Aggregate()
          .Find(Builders<Settings>.Filter.Empty)
          .Project<TSettings>(new BsonDocument()
          {
                { "User", "$(TSettings).user" },
                { "Password", "$(TSettings).password" },
                { "BaseUri", "$(TSettings).baseUri" },
          });
        
    return settings;
}
```

These above methods works, but I need a generic version. It's possible make it without "specificate" model property or without instantiating classes "manually"?

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure if it's possible without using aggregation, but you can use $replaceRoot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795754/replace-root-with-c-sharp-driver-for-net-core-aggregateexpressiondefinition

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama How can I use `$replaceRoot` without specify the inner path? Like `.ReplaceRoot<TSettings >("$mySubNode")` ?

Comment: If you didn't specify the property to use as root, how would it know which property to use? For all the .NET driver knows, `PartnerASettings` is a common type that you use many times in a single document.

Comment: Yep, that's why I created this question. The answer maybe is "NO": I CAN'T use `.Project`, `.As`, `.ReplaceRoot`, `etc...`  without "instantiate object" or "without specify the property".

Comment: Do you just want to use `typeof(TSettings).Name` as the property name? Or what? Is the goal here that `PartnerASettings` and `PartnerBSettings` will sometimes contain different properties? If not, wouldn't it be better to architect this as a dictionary or a list?

Comment: No, use typeof(TSettings).Name isn't an option. Yes, `PartnerASettings` and `PartnerBSettings` will have different properties.

Comment: Why isn't it an option? I don't really get your idea here. It seems like you want to pluck the property name out of thin air?

Comment: Isn't an option only to avoid things like: `.ReplaceRoot<TSettings>($"${JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase.ConvertName(typeof(TSettings).Name)}")` since our collection is `camelCase` and model is `PascalCase`. The idea here is understand why only `.Project<TSettings>` doesn't works.

Comment: [Aggregate project documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [Query projection documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). If you look in `Builders<Settings>.Projection.` do you see anything to do what you want to do, because last time I checked there was not.

Comment: Yeah, probably we can't without specify ou create a `BsonDocument`.